# How to combine ng-view with complete pages in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug, single-page-application

I am developing an application that is supposed to be a single-page application.
The tools I am using are AngularJS, NodeJS, ExpressJS and Jade for templating.

So far I've been working with a page that has a ng-view directive on it, and I can change its content to display the page I want, while maintaining the side menu.

Now I've come to a point where I need to create a login/create account page (that I am calling 'intro', for now), and this one should use all the screen space, removing the menu as well.

How can I achieve this? My route file looks as follows:

```js
var akaAcademicManagerApp = angular.module('akaAcademicManagerApp', ['ngRoute', 'akaAcademicControllers']);

akaAcademicManagerApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
      }).
      when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/profile',
        controller: 'ProfileController'
      }).
      when('/intro', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/introPage',
        controller: 'IntroController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/dashboard'
      });
  }]);

angular.module('akaAcademicControllers', []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you (yet, i don't think it's the optimal solution but it works)

in your index.html,after your body tag put this:

```
<div ng-include="accessToApplication()"></div>
```

Now in your controller:

```
$scope.loggedIn = false;// true when the user is logged in

$scope.accessToApplication = function () {
            if (!$scope.loggedIn) {
                return "partials/introPage.html";
            }
            else {
                return "path to the page containing the ng-view";
                }
};
```

I advice you to take a look at ui-router and multiple named views (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: But I would need to have both of these paths mapped, right? I don't know how to do a simple redirect without having the page routed  in my ngRoute file.
Any redirect I make through the route file only changes which partial page is going to be displayed into the index's ng-view

Comment: remove when('/intro', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/introPage',
        controller: 'IntroController'
      }) from your config.
The page going to be displayed is the one declared in otherwise ( ==> dashbord)

Comment: What if I had two pages that needed to behave like this? I depend on the Otherwise method I believe.
Most likely I will have about 3-4 pages that are not partial and need to be displayed as full pages.